# how to get char column type in mysql as string in entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-5

Created entity model from MySql database. The table column of type char(16) is converted as System.Guid in entity.

All the code is based on string as i have used Sql Server for the application before. Now after converting the entity from MySql am having this problem. All over the code i have custome objects where i have used these as strings.

Tried to use some tricks from the articles i read but no use. done using the old connector/net but no use.

How can i get char type column in mySql as string?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and C# convert types different.
Example:

varchar will be returned as a `string` for C#

char will be returned as a `System.GUID`

blob will be returned as a `byte[]`

As far as I know there is no such thing to convert them.
Maybe a little workaround for you would be converting them in the `set`

```
      [NotMapped]
      private string _converter { get; set; }
      [Column(TypeName = "char"), StringLength(16)] 
      public string MyProperty 
      {
       get
       {
         return this._converter;
       }
       set
       {
         this._converter = Convert.ToString(value);
       }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and its working fine but, if we have 1 or 2 instances we can do this aslo i hope when we refresh the model we will loose this custom property on set. I have 37 instances where i have to use the custom property. Instead i changed the DB column type to Char(35) instead Char(36) then refreshed the model and changed the column type to string. Thought this was the minimal change i can do and its solved my problem

Comment: Yeah changing the type seems to be the best solve for this case, didn't exactly knew how you are using that column. But glas to help and to see you got a solution :)